# Move imagefile based on CSV cell data

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, csv, directory

I know this is intro stuff but I'm not a programmer and I've been working on this for days and I'm about to beat my dog..

I have a csv file with imagenames and attributes, i.e.,

12-123.png,M

12-124.png,F

12-241.phg,M

...

and I'm trying to move them into respective directories, "orig_png/m/" or "orig_png/f/", based on the second row data, "M" or "F". I've tried every script I've found online, and there's always some problem, so I modified one that was close to what I needed and I could understand what was going on.. I know I've probably mangled this, but here's what I have (most PRINT statements were for me to see what was happening):

```
# Import csv
import csv
# Import os
import os, shutil
# Main Function
# def main():
# Open dataset file
# dataset = open('database_png.csv', newline='')
dataset = open('database_png.csv')
path = "home/darryl/Machine_Learning/ribs/200x200/orig_png/"
moveto1 = "home/darryl/Machine_Learning/ribs/200x200/orig_png/m/"
moveto2 = "home/darryl/Machine_Learning/ribs/200x200/orig_png/f/"
# Initialize csvreader for dataset
reader = csv.reader(dataset)
# Read data from reader
data = list(reader)
# Variables for progress counter
lines = len(data)
i = 0
# Analyze data in dataset
for row in data:
# Assign image name and state to variables
image = row[0]
state = row[1]
# Print image information
print image
print state
print('({}/{}) Processing image ({}): {}'.format(i + 1, lines, state, image))
# Increment i
i += 1
print moveto1
# Determine action to perform
if state is "M":
    print moveto1+image
    src = path+image
    dst = moveto1+image
    dst1 = moveto2+image
    shutil.move(src,dst)
elif state is "F"
    shutil.move(src,dst1)
```

mostly error messages are,
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'home/darryl/Machine_Learning/ribs/200x200/orig_png/12-094.png', when it LOOKS like it's correct, and

File "move4.py", line 39
    elif state is "F"
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

If someone could help me with a simple way to do this (I know I've made this more complicated than necessary), I would be extremely grateful, and I might even learn something in the process!

NOTE: Here is the cut down file, but still errors. how do I fix this?

```
import csv
import os, shutil
dataset = open('database_png.csv')
path = "/home/darryl/Machine_Learning/ribs/200x200/orig_png/"
moveto = "/home/darryl/Machine_Learning/ribs/200x200/orig_png/m/"
reader = csv.reader(dataset)
data = list(reader)
lines = len(data)
i = 0
for row in data:
    image = row[0]
    state = row[1]
    i += 1
    if state is "M":
        src = path+image
        dst = moveto+image
        shutil.move(src,dst)
```

Comment: You've got some indentation issues in the posted code. it would help to fix them up.

Comment: Your `elif` doesn't have a colon at the end. When that's fixed, you calculate `dst1` in the `if` but use it in the `elif`? That won't work!. Note that your path names are relative. Did you want a leading / there? (e.g., /home/darryl/...).

Comment: ok, I know my error is with path (relative, abs), and I must admit, this really confuses me. So to be easier, I've trimmed it down to basics, but still get "No such file or directory: '/home/darryl/Machine_Learning/ribs/200x200/orig_png/12-094.png'" even with this:

Comment: (I've added new script to above)

Comment: Does the file exist? Its just a name in a CSV. That error tells you that the file named in the CSV isn't there.